# Issues when starting up RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, startup

Just installed R and Rstudio on my laptop, but keep running into this error messages in the console tab. Should I be worried?

Here is the error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stats’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.0/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

During startup

```
 - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.0/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Is this actually preventing R or RStudio from functioning? What have you tried to do?

Comment: I tried uninstalling and re-installing, but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 1):

The following workaround worked for me. 
After all the installs as recommended try this last step.
"Change the name of the .Reviron file in probably your Documents folder to anything else so that it is not found by the code."
This was created for rtools. I renamed it .Renvironx